# TensorFlow - cannot recreate neural network

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network

I am trying to recreate/rerun a previous neural network. The idea is that I save the weights and biases with which the network is initialised in run (1), and reuse those exact weights and biases for initialisation in run (2), so that the outcome of run (2) will be exactly that of run (1). The relevant code is below.

However, I can't manage to do this. If I rerun the network, setting `use_stored_weights` to `True` (which prompts `neural_network_model` to restore the previously saved weights and biases, and, I hope, initialise the network with them), I do indeed always get the same results - but these are not the results of the run I am trying to emulate (in fact, they are much worse). It is also strange that I ALWAYS get the same results - they thus seem to be independent of the stored weights and biases.

The first thing I checked is whether I am correctly restoring my weights and biases (in `neural_network_model`), and this is the case.

I'm not really sure what is going on here. I have two suspicions, both of which I don't know how to check:

- Although the correct weights and biases are restored in `neural_network_model`, the network is in fact not initialised with them. Is it the command `sess.run(init)` in `train_neural_network` that somehow does this?
- I am reinitialising the network with the stored weights and biases not once, but every time - this would explain the poor results.

... but it might as well be something completely different. Any help much appreciated!

UPDATE: I figured out what is happening: when `use_stored_weights` is set to `True`, the weights are always initialised as all zeros. As far as I can see, this is due to the `sess.run(init)` in `train_neural_network`. However, if I leave out that line, I get an error:

```
FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value b2
```

So I guess my question is now: how can I make the restored weights and biases accessible in `train_neural_network`?

Imports:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from numpy import genfromtxt
```

This function builds the neural network:

```
def neural_network_model(data, layer_sizes, use_stored_weights):
    num_layers = len(layer_sizes) - 1 # hidden and output layers
    weights = {}
    biases = {}

    # initialise the weights
    # (a) create new weights and biases
    if not use_stored_weights:
        for i in range(num_layers):            
            w_name = 'W' + str(i+1)
            b_name = 'b' + str(i+1)
            weights[w_name] = tf.get_variable(w_name, [layer_sizes[i], layer_sizes[i+1]], 
                initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(), dtype=tf.float32)
            biases[b_name] = tf.get_variable(b_name, [layer_sizes[i+1]], 
                initializer = tf.zeros_initializer(), dtype=tf.float32)

        # save weights and biases
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
            save_path = saver.save(sess, fold_path + 'weights/' + 'weights.ckpt')

    # (b) restore weights and biases
    else:
        for i in range(num_layers):
            # prepare variable
            w_name = 'W' + str(i+1)
            b_name = 'b' + str(i+1)
            weights[w_name] = tf.get_variable(w_name, [layer_sizes[i], layer_sizes[i+1]], 
                initializer = tf.zeros_initializer(), dtype=tf.float32)
            biases[b_name] = tf.get_variable(b_name, [layer_sizes[i+1]], 
                initializer = tf.zeros_initializer(), dtype=tf.float32)

        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            saver.restore(sess, fold_path + 'weights/' + 'weights.ckpt')

    # calculate linear and relu outputs for hidden layers
    a_prev = data
    for i in range(len(weights)-1):    
        z = tf.add(tf.matmul(a_prev, weights['W' + str(i+1)]), biases['b' + str(i+1)])
        a = tf.nn.relu(z)
        a_r = tf.nn.dropout(a, keep_prob)
        a_prev = a_r
    # calculate linear output for output layer
    z_o = tf.add(tf.matmul(a_prev, weights['W' + str(len(weights))]), biases['b' + str(len(weights))])

    return z_o
```

This function trains and evaluates the network:

```
def train_neural_network(x, layer_sizes, use_stored_weights):
    prediction = neural_network_model(x, layer_sizes, use_stored_weights)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=y))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=lrn_rate).minimize(cost)

    softm = tf.nn.softmax(prediction)
    pred_class = tf.argmax(softm)
    costs = []
    correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1)) 
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)
        for epoch in range(epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0
            for _ in range(int(len(x_train)/batch_size)):
                epoch_x, epoch_y = x_train, y_train
                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict = {x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y, keep_prob: kp})
                epoch_loss += c

        softmaxes_tst = sess.run([softm, pred_class], feed_dict={x: x_test, keep_prob: 1.0})[0]
        incorr = 0
        for i in range(len(softmaxes_tst)):
            curr_sm = softmaxes_tst[i]
            curr_lbl = y_test[i]
            if np.argmax(curr_sm) != np.argmax(curr_lbl):
                incorr += 1

        print('incorr: ', incorr)
        num_ex = len(x_test)
        print('acc = ' + str(num_ex-incorr) + '/' + str(num_ex) + ' = ' + str((num_ex-incorr)/num_ex))

        print('accuracy train:', accuracy.eval({x:x_train, y:y_train, keep_prob: kp}))         
        print('accuracy test :', accuracy.eval({x:x_test, y:y_test, keep_prob: 1.0}))
```

And this, finally, is the code that calls the above functions:

```
lrn_rate = 0.01
kp = 0.85
epochs = 400

path = '/my/path/to/data/'
fold_path = ''
num_folds = 19

for i in range(num_folds):
    tf.reset_default_graph()

    fold_path = path + 'fold_' + str(i+1) + '/'
    x_train = genfromtxt(fold_path + 'fv_train.csv', delimiter=',')
    y_train = genfromtxt(fold_path + 'lbl_train.csv', delimiter=',')
    x_test  = genfromtxt(fold_path + 'fv_test.csv', delimiter=',')
    y_test  = genfromtxt(fold_path + 'lbl_test.csv', delimiter=',')

    num_classes = len(y_train[0])
    num_features = len(x_train[0])
    batch_size = len(x_train)  

    num_nodes_hl1 = num_features
    num_nodes_hl2 = num_features

    layer_sizes = [num_features, num_nodes_hl1, num_nodes_hl2, num_classes]

    x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, num_features])
    y = tf.placeholder('float')
    keep_prob = tf.placeholder('float')

    use_stored_weights = True 
    train_neural_network(x, layer_sizes, use_stored_weights)
```

Comment: Why not use the checkpoint feature of tensorflow to save training state and continue later?

Comment: Isn't that what I am doing?